# Redshift ERROR: Column (name) has unsupported type interval

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In Redshift I'm trying to create a table wherein I subtract a datetime from another datetime, where the original data is a string, and arrive at a difference to the nearest millisecond.

```
(SPLIT_PART((MAX(event_start_datetime_ms) OVER (partition by visit_id)), 'T', 2) :: time - SPLIT_PART(event_start_datetime_ms,'T',2) :: time) as time_diff
```

I can run a select statement fine, but when trying to create a table I'm getting the following:

> [0A000] ERROR: Column "time_diff" has unsupported type "interval".

Apparently Redshift tables can't handle the "interval" data type. I tried casting it as a string but that mangles the results. Casting it as time gives this error:

> ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not
> supported on Redshift tables.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Window function within a function is not supported, Try this instead :

```
select SPLIT_PART(max_event_start_datetime_ms, 'T', 2) :: time 
       - SPLIT_PART(event_start_datetime_ms, 'T', 2) :: time  as time_diff
from (
  select *, MAX(event_start_datetime_ms) OVER (partition by visit_id) max_event_start_datetime_ms
  from mytable
) as s
```

Comment: The window-within-function is fine as long as I'm just running a select statement. Its only when I try to save it to a table that it breaks.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the full update query and table definition